# GEE-Select pixels whose values equal to a given value in an image

Tags: google-earth-engine

There is a classified image in which each pixel has a class number.
I want to select those pixels with the same class number.
Then do some statistics such as mean for those selected pixels.
How can I achieve this goal?
Looking forward for your instruction!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say your image has a band called `'class'` and you want the pixels where the class is `3`. Then you could write:

```
var onlyClass3Image = classifiedImage.updateMask(
  classifiedImage.select('class').eq(3));
```

`.eq(3)` computes an image which is 1 where the input pixel is 3 and 0 where it is not, which we then use as a mask to remove pixels from the original image.

Comment: Thank you for your instruction! That is exactly what I want!